# How to delete broken ralations?

Tags: parse-platform

during development some objects in my current project has been deleted in the database.

But those objects may have been used as one-to-one-relation in other objects and I would like to avoid them from been fetched (or delete them in a cron)

But I have no idea how to query those objects:
I tried

```
var query = Parse.Object.extend("A");
query.include("b");
query.exists("b");
```

But even if "b" does not exist no more - there is a relation with that "not existing objectId".

Comment: Check out [beforeDelete/afterDelete hook](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-ondelete).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your fast reply. I already know that hook, but those hooks does not help me if the relations are already broken...

Comment: Okay, then you need 2 query one for A and one for B(<-b) and use `doesNotMatchQuery` where inner query is a query to B. Something like, `var q1 = new Parse.Query('B'); var q2 = new Parse.Query('A'); q2.doesNotMatchQuery('b', q1); q2.find().then(...)`

Comment: Also note that, both query have the limit of the number of results (default 100/max 1000).

Comment: Ah, yes that should work! Thanks...